# I can't login using the axios API for React Native

Tags: javascript, service, react-native, authorization, axios

I'm new in React Native.
I'm trying to write an Http class for supporting/service purpose, but the authorization endpoint doesn't work getting me always **status 401** which doesn't make sense given that the endpoint doesn't need any token/authorization but on the contrary it should return me a token

my service:

```
constructor() {
  let $this = this;
  this.__proto__.ghtnk = null;
  axios.defaults.baseURL = this.getBaseUrlApi().test;
  axios.defaults.headers.common['Content-Type'] = 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8';

  axios.interceptors.request.use(function (config) {
  console.log(config, axios.defaults.headers);
  $this.getToken().then((token) => {
    console.log(token);
    if (token) {
      console.log('TOKEN:', token);
      axios.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = 'Bearer ' + token;
    }
  });
  return config;
  }, function (error) {
    // Do something with request error
    return Promise.reject(error);
  });

}

post = (url, payload) => {
  axios.post( url, payload).then((resp) => {
    console.log(resp);
  }, (err) => {
    console.log(err);
  });
}
```

[image]

Comment: Since you already found the solution I would like to kindly ask you to write an answer to your question and accept it after two days, make sure that the answer is not part of the question.

Answer (score 1):

I sorted it out doing this

```
post = (url, payload) => {
  let params = new URLSearchParams();
  params.append('username', payload.username);
  params.append('password', payload.password);
  axios.post( url, params).then((resp) => {
        console.log(resp);
  }, (err) => {
        console.log(err);
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I struggled with a problem like that once, turns out there was a "/" at the end of my URL and axis simply can't deal with that... Once I removed it worked again.

e.g

before: http:/apihost/etc/

after: http:/apihost/etc

hope it helps